# Books that follow axiomatic approach?

Tags: reference-request

What are some maths textbooks that follow the "axiomatic approach"? (I would call it "theorem-proof" approach, but I'm more after books that start from the complete basics in a branch of math)

What I consider "axiomatic approach" books: e.g. Disquisitiones Arithmeticae, Euclid's Elements

Comment: Try the Bourbaki series.

Answer (score 4):

Anything by [Nicolas Bourbaki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki). Some specific recommendations:

1. *Algebra* [1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540642439) and [2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540007067).
2. [*Commutative algebra*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540642390).
3. *Integration* [1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540642390) and [2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642058213).
4. *Lie groups and Lie algebras*, [1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540642420), [2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540691715) and [3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/354068851X).

Bourbaki is *very far* from being suitable for everyone. That said, if you're looking for a reference that's axiomatic, super-abstract, and works in greatest possible generality, and is also crystal clear and careful, Bourbaki is the place to go.

Also, I'd say that Grothendieck's [*Éléments de géométrie algébrique*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89l%C3%A9ments_de_g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie_alg%C3%A9brique) is *the* axiomatic reference for algebraic geometry.

Comment: Can you tell me which book(s) of Bourbaki treats abstract algebra?

Comment: @user 170039: That would be the books titled "algebra." (In serious math, we refer to "abstract algebra" as just "algebra.")

Comment: All the two books, right?

Comment: @user 170093: yes.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Foundations of Analysis](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.math.uic.edu%2F~kauffman%2FLandau.pdf&ei=mSxJVJ-KO8PVmAWq84CIBA&usg=AFQjCNGSxcLRc7tgfBrowdCr-d6OWVEbAg) by E. Landau.
2. [The Foundations of Geometry](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gutenberg.org%2Ffiles%2F17384%2F17384-pdf.pdf&ei=_yxJVKjRBILcmgXT7oHYAw&usg=AFQjCNEg0gx46fbBIbG9fSo5Ubs9fS2I-A) by D. Hilbert.
3. [Galois Theory](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.scribd.com%2Fdoc%2F91411934%2FGalois-Theory-by-Cox&ei=_S1JVLeGH-PBmwWdpID4Aw&usg=AFQjCNGELUO0tPIaIHOssu8FXniK4biFfw&bvm=bv.77880786,d.dGY) by D. Cox.
4. [Principles of Mathematics](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CFoQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Farchive.org%2Fdetails%2Fprinciplesmathe00russgoog&ei=OTBJVJbtBJKn8AWw-oCoDg&usg=AFQjCNHinMO07weAeBPkK7YjDf6fCAVSuA&bvm=bv.77880786,d.dGc) by B. Russell.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some books that include constructions of the real numbers from the natural numbers:

- [Number Systems and the Foundations of Analysis](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486457923.html) by Mendelson
- [The Number System](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486458067.html) by Thurston
- *The Structure of Number Systems* by Parker