# Reference for the Construction of the integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, integers

Please, could you recommend me some books, articles or lecture notes about the Construction of the integers ?

Thank you!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987564/books-that-follow-axiomatic-approach

Comment: "God made the integers, all the rest is the work of man." -- Kronecker.

Answer (score 2):

- *The Number Systems: Foundations of Algebra and Analysis*, Solomon Feferman, AMS Chelsea Publishing, 1989 — chapter 4
- *Retracing Elementary Mathematics*, Leon Henkin, W. Norman Smith, Verne J. Varineau and Michael J. Walsh, MacMillan, 1962 — chapter XI
- *Foundations of Analysis*, Edmund Landau, AMS Chelsea Publishing, 1966 — § II.5

Comment: Thank you, But please did you still remember the number of the page which I can found  it

Comment: I've added references to the chapters.

Answer (score 2):

- [Number Systems and the Foundations of Analysis](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486457923.html) by Mendelson
- [The Number System](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486458067.html) by Thurston
- *The Structure of Number Systems* by Parker