# Number system construction book recommendation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, book-recommendation, foundations

I am coming to the end of 'a logical introduction to proof' by Cunningham and was thinking of continuing with some foundational topics.

As such i think i may try the following:

1. [Set Theory: A First Course by Cunningham](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Set-Theory-Cambridge-Mathematical-Textbooks/dp/1107120322)
2. [Mathematical Logic by Chiswell](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Logic-Oxford-Texts-Book-ebook/dp/B001DWNGEQ/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=B001HCVS88&qid=1557948654&rd=1&s=gateway&sr=8-2)

Does anyone have any experience with these and are they decent?

Also,could someone offer their opinions regarding the following two books focused on the foundation of numbers?

1. The Number Systems of Analysis by Little,Teo,Brunt.
2. Number Systems And the foundations of analysis by Mendelson

It is difficult to find previews/pdf files for them. The second one seems more comprehensive but also feels a bit dated.

Thank you for any views in any case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829439/reference-for-the-construction-of-the-integers and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498656/real-analysis-rigourous-definition-of-real-numbers

Answer (score 0):

A very acccessible reference: Peterson, Theory of Arithmetic.

(Available at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/TheoryOfArithmetic/page/n3))